# Codeigniter mkdir: Permission denied error

Tags: codeigniter

How to resolve these errors?

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Warning
>
> Message: mkdir(): Permission denied
>
> Filename: drivers/Session_files_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 136
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /var/www/html/application/controllers/Home.php
>
> Line: 8
>
> Function: __construct
>
> File: /var/www/html/index.php
>
> Line: 315
>
> Function: require_once
>
> Warning: Uncaught Exception: Session: Configured save path '/var/www/html/application/cache/session' is not a directory, doesn't exist or cannot be created. in /var/www/html/system/libraries/Session/drivers/Session_files_driver.php:138 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: CI_Session_files_driver->open('/var/www/html/a...', 'ci_session') #1 /var/www/html/system/libraries/Session/Session.php(143): session_start() #2 /var/www/html/system/core/Loader.php(1281): CI_Session->__construct() #3 /var/www/html/system/core/Loader.php(1174): CI_Loader->_ci_init_library('Session', 'CI_', NULL, 'session') #4 /var/www/html/system/core/Loader.php(1037): CI_Loader->_ci_load_stock_library('Session', 'Session/', NULL, NULL) #5 /var/www/html/system/core/Loader.php(1082): CI_Loader->_ci_load_library('Session', NULL, NULL) #6 /var/www/html/system/core/Loader.php(218): CI_Loader->_ci_load_library('Session', NULL, NULL) #7 /var/www/html/system/core/Loader.php(202): CI_Loader->library('session', NULL) #8 /var/www/html/system/core/Loader.php(13 in /var/www/html/system/libraries/Session/drivers/Session_files_driver.php on line 138
>
> Fatal error: session_start(): Failed to initialize storage module: user (path: /var/www/html/application/cache/session) in /var/www/html/system/libraries/Session/Session.php on line 143
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Error
>
> Message: session_start(): Failed to initialize storage module: user (path: /var/www/html/application/cache/session)
>
> Filename: Session/Session.php
>
> Line Number: 143
>
> Backtrace:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're using an apache2-Webserver, check the directory permissions for `/var/www/html/application/cache/session`. It has to be legible and writable for `www-data` user.

To set the permissions, simply run `sudo chown -R www-data /var/www/html` and `sudo chmod -R u+rw /var/www/html`. This sets the directory permissions recursively to your webroot and all subdirectories.